# Using SendKeys from vbs in a total hidden way?

Tags: windows-7, router, cmd.exe, telnet, vbscript

Here is what I am planning to do

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
WshShell.Run"cmd"
WshShell.AppActivate"telnet 192.168.1.1"     
WScript.Sleep 50    
WshShell.SendKeys"telnet 192.168.1.1 -f 22.txt{ENTER}" 
WScript.Sleep 2000    
WshShell.SendKeys "admin{ENTER}"     
WScript.sleep 50     
WshShell.SendKeys"sys info{ENTER}"   
WScript.Sleep 50
```

I want this totally hidden but the `sendkeys` just works on activated window so trying to make it hidden by minimizing the window failed. 
I couldn't find any understandable way to do this

Is this possible without additional tools?

Comment: "Did you read over ss64.com/vb/run.html and see the section labeled Invisible.vbs" yes i did ............is there any way to hide that "cmd window running the telnet commands with sendkeys" that what i have meant in the first place. or the sendkeys can be replaced with something else ?

Comment: but how can i get it automaticed ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I found is using [AutoIt Scripting Language](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

```
DllCall("kernel32.dll", "boolean", "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection", "boolean", 1) 
Run('cmd',"",@SW_HIDE) Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:cmd]", "", 1) 
Sleep (250) 
ControlSend("C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe","","","telnet 192.168.1.1 -f log.txt{ENTER}") 
Sleep (2500) 
ControlSend("Telnet 192.168.1.1","","","pass1{ENTER}") 
ControlSend("Telnet 192.168.1.1","","","sysinfo{ENTER}") 
Sleep (1500) 
WinClose("Telnet 192.168.1.1")
```

Comment: `DllCall("kernel32.dll", "boolean", "Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection", "boolean", 1)
Run('cmd',"",@SW_HIDE)
Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:cmd]", "", 1)
Sleep (250)
ControlSend("C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe","","","telnet 192.168.1.1 -f log.txt{ENTER}")
Sleep (2500)
ControlSend("Telnet 192.168.1.1","","","pass1{ENTER}")
ControlSend("Telnet 192.168.1.1","","","sysinfo{ENTER}")
Sleep (1500)
WinClose("Telnet 192.168.1.1")`

Comment: a screen shot of the organized one as i could not organize it in the comments
https://i.imgur.com/KUGYN17.png